# Please help interpret the IBM Quantum error code: "Instruction bfunc is not supported [7001]"

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I have already run the circuit on the IBM Quantum simulators successfully. But, when I ran the same circuit on the real quantum device ***ibmq_16_melbourne***, I got the error. The IBM website does have the `7001` code definition, but it is not specific enough to indicate what the `bfunc` means.

Could you please help interpret the code? More important, how can I avoid that to have a successful run?

Thanks.

Comment: If it possible, then put your code here so we can see what you did and maybe someone can further assist you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `bfunc` is a *Boolean Function*, as defined in the [QObj Specification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03452) (page 20) and the error `7001` [refers to](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/manage/errors#id5) `Instruction {} is not supported`.

In other words, *the backend `ibmq_16_melbourne` does not support boolean functions*.

Your circuit has, most likely, a classical conditional, something like `if (c==0) h q[0];` in QASM or a `circuit.h(qreg_q[0]).c_if(creg_c, 0)` in Qiskit. Conditional are not currently (March 2021) supported by any of the IBM quantum hardware. Although, they supported in many simulators.

Comment: Precisely. Thanks, sir. I used that in our QASM files. Any plans to implement that this year? I use the one-bit trick inverse QFT described in the _OpenQASM_ spec to do the 2n+3 Shor's Algorithm. It must have conditional statements. Imagine it saves n qubits!

Comment: I mean, one-bit inverse QFT saves (n-1) qubits:-)

Comment: What you describe sounds to me like *dynamic circuits*. My understanding from the roadmap is that is planned for 2022 https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2021/02/quantum-development-roadmap/

Comment: You said the conditional statements are supported in many simulators. I tested them and they accepted the syntax indeed. But, are you aware of any problems of using them? I can run a toy circuit (factoring 21) with full Quantum Fourier Transform (meaning no conditional statements) successfully on them, but not one-bit QFT. But, I can run both on simulators from other companies successfully. The one-bit QFT on _ibmq_qasm_simulator_ does not produce the correct results. Do you have a good example of using one-bit QFT?

Comment: that sounds like a new question :)